# Creating an exam system

Tags: 7

I am trying to create an examination system with Drupal, and I am not sure how to implement it. I can see many ways to do it, but I am not sure which one is the best way to achieve it.

These are the features am looking at:

- Users should have the ability to add questions under different subjects.
- Users will take test by answering optional answers (radio buttons).
- Users can move back and forward between answers and mark for later reviewing.
- In the end the result will be shown.
- Users can also choose the number of questions they want, and the difficulty level.

[image: This is a mockup of how the a test will look.]

What is the best way to achieve this? This is what I am doing.

1. I added a content type question.
2. I added `options` field for answer option and `right-option`field for the right answer.
3. I added a drop down field for difficulty level.
4. I created a taxonomy term list for subject and connected with content type.

From here, what is the best thing to do?
Is creating a view page and giving the limit as per page one a good idea? If so how will I give the options of answer as radio/options, or should I create a custom page from module and take the answers using JSON?
What will be the right and easiest way to achieve this?

[image: Mockup of result after taking test]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [Closed Question](http://drupal.org/project/closedquestion) module.
You can find more information about the module [here](http://wmmrc.nl/drupal-modules/closedquestion).

> #### Features
>
> - Designed for practicing: students can take as many attempts as they like.
> - Many feedback options, feedback can change with attempts.
> - Many question types.
> - Questions can be added anywhere in a site.
> - Only Questions. Ordering questions in a quiz or case is done by a separate module.

Answer (score 2):

I am looking to perform something similar for a project. I have not gotten into more than a cursory consideration yet, but would immediately recommend looking at the [Quiz contributed module](http://drupal.org/project/quiz). Its V7.x version is still a dev. level module, but if it appears to do everything and more that you could want. If not, check out the related modules on the project page.

At the very least, it will provide a reference for how to accomplish many of the tasks you will need to meet your requirements.

As Kolo mentions, Closed question also relates to your concept and it has another list of related projects.  Please return to this question and let us know what you find out as you investigate, I am interested in what you learn!

Comment: I am going through it. Will definitely post back.