# Strange question pertaining views as forms?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, webforms

I am attempting to provide quizzes in Drupal. The Drupal quiz module is out of question as a version for Drupal 7 does not exist. The way to go about doing this then IMHO is using web-forms. I am treating each question that is part of the quiz as a separate node entity.

The idea is to cluster these questions based on taxonomy vocabularies and establish a quiz. Clearly the best way to have nodes together would be VIEWS with some filter criterion. However, this clearly backfires. It establishes the required set of questions as a view. But this does not necessarily establish them a single quiz form, but rather a set of individual forms all present in the single page. Essentially, if my view has 10 questions, then it has 10 SUBMIT buttons.

My aim is to try and create this view as a form, but I think that is not possible anymore. I feel I should just post this here, regardless to get an answer or alternative ways to go about doing this.

Comment: Here is a link to similar question:  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21990/creating-an-exam-system-with-drupal-7/22024#22024

Comment: I have a little half-finished module for doing this, if you want to wade through it: https://github.com/bbinkovitz/derpl/ It's the one called "webformta".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Views would be the way I'd go with this. It's for getting data displayed from the database and this just seems like you're stretching the scope of what it's designed to do.

Is there any reason each question has to be on a different node? That seems to be adding even more complexity.

My suggestion would be to use webform to a the form for each different quiz. Especially if site administrators will have to create the quizzes regularly as webform offers the best UI for doing this. The difficult bit then is to write some sort of add on to webform (I don't know how much of an API webform has) that changes how the form is submitted and validated to be more 'quiz like'.